# compare file names in array using shell

Tags: shell

I am new to `shell` script.
I've put few file-names in array. I want to compare them & select the file name with lowest number.

*Example:*

> file1: ab3_10_10_10.txt
>   file2: ab3_8_8_8.txt
>   file3: ab3_7_7_7.txt

in above example, file3 should be selected as the needed file.
I only want to make selection based on the name, using shell.

```
files=(ab3*)  # adding files to array

files=("${files[@]##*/}")                        # removing the full address from the name

echo "what is in the array:" ${files[@]}         # lists what is in the array.
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BASH you can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
pos=
min=
i=0
for f in "${files[@]//[^0-9]/}"; do
   [[ -z $min || $f -lt $min ]] && min=$f && pos=$i
   ((i++))
done

echo "min-file: ${files[$pos]}"
min-file: ab3_7_7_7.txt
```

Comment: I tried doing it, it says vote up requires 15 reputation.  i just signed up and have 6 reputation.

Comment: No don't try to vote up. Just click on tick mark on top-left of my answer and it will turn green.

Comment: ok, sorry. just did.  can i ask an other question.  i am trying to use reqex, pattern matcing, to split this string in to separate variables, "abc12c20m.  where var1=abc,var2=12, and var3=20.  main string could differ for exp "abc2c5m", but "abc" part is always the same.

Comment: This sounds like a totally different problem and not easy to post code in comments, please post a new question I will respond back with examples also.

Comment: ok, just did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120392/parse-using-pattern-matching-in-shell

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is loop through the array and use "sort -V":

```
# set the array
arr=( ab3_10_10_10.txt ab3_8_8_8.txt ab3_7_7_7.txt )

# loop through the array and sort, then pick the first one at the end
count=0
for i in ${arr[@]}; do
  echo $i
done | \
sort -V | \
while read i; do
  [[ $count = 0 ]] && echo $i
  (( count++ ))
done
```

This gives:

```
ab3_7_7_7.txt
```

The "-V" flag for "sort" is critical for sorting more complicated strings with numbers in them.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I got a invalid option for -V. "sort: invalid option -- V"

Comment: Which sort are you using? Unfortunately, busybox's sort doesn't have the "-V" option. Implementing it would be difficult.

Comment: user> which sort
/bin/sort