# parse using pattern matching in shell

Tags: shell, pattern-matching

I am trying to use reqex, pattern matching, to split this string in to separate variables, **abc12c20m**. where:

```
var1=abc
var2=12
var3=20
```

Main string could differ for exp **abc2c5m**, but **abc** part is always the same and **c** and **m** are always in the string.  One solution must work for both **abc12c20m** and **abc2c5m**.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BASH regex:

```
s='abc12c20m'
if [[ "$s" =~ ^(abc)([0-9]+)c([0-9]+)m$ ]]; then 
    var1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    var2=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    var3=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
fi

echo "$var1 - $var2 - $var3"
abc - 12 - 20
```

Comment: You're probably not using BASH. Make sure to use bash for this parsing.

Comment: ./arry_test.sh: line 42: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token (' ./arry_test.sh: line 42: syntax error near ^(a' ./arry_test.sh: line 42: `if [[ "$s" =~ ^(abc)([0-9]+)c([0-9]+)m$ ]]; then '

Comment: And what if "abc" part changes to "cba"?

Comment: You're certainly making a mistake in copy/paste. **[see it working here](http://ideone.com/TKFcHz)**

Comment: i copied correctly, and download your version from given link but still got same error.  is there another way to write this in shell?

Comment: You can see it working online in that demo so all you need to do is copy/paste, save as `script.sh` and then run `bash ./script.sh`. This is BASH specific syntax so no `sh`

Comment: @fali, if **abc** part changes to **cba** you must specify it in your question. In addition, this solution works properly.

Comment: or due to older bash version where this regex support is unavailable.?? this solution works fine otherwise.

Comment: I think it's my BASH version.  I'll see if i can update my bash, but in the mean time is there any other way to do this in shell?

Comment: @fali: try: `read var1 var2 var3 < <(echo "$s" | sed 's/^\(abc\)\([0-9]*\)c\([0-9]*\)m$/\1 \2 \3/')`